Find the probability from here that $I$ asnd $J$ overlap.
The numbers $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}$ are chosen at random in the interval $[0,1]$. Let $I$ be the interval between $x_{1},x_{2}$ and $J$ be the interval between $x_{3}$ and $x_{4}$. Find the Probability that the intervals $I$ and $J$ overlap.
What I observed so far is that if $I = [x_1,x_2]$ and $J = [x_3,x_4]$ has to intersect then we must have either $$x_1 \le x_3 \le x_2 \le x_4, x_1 \le x_3 \le x_4 \le x_2$$ or $$x_3 \le x_1 \le x_4 \le x_2, x_3 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le x_4.$$
Now how can we find the probability from here that $I$ asnd $J$ overlap?
Source: AOPS

For non-overlapping condition, you must have that $\max(x_{1},x_{2})\leq \min(x_{3},x_{4})$ or $\max(x_{3},x_{4})\leq \min(x_{1},x_{2})$ .
Let us consider the first case.
See that this happens when we have the following in ascending order $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4})$ .
Now $(x_{1},x_{2})$ can be interchanged with each other and $(x_{3},x_{4})$ can be interchanged and we would still have the first case being satisfied.
So, the total number of orderings of $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}$ such that the first case holds is $2\times 2=4$.
Similarly, there are 4 more cases for the second case. So in total, there are 8 possible orderings of $4$ numbers such that the intervals don't overlap.
The total number of orderings is $4!=24$. So the probability that the intervals don't overlap is $\frac{8}{24}=\frac{1}{3}$ and hence the probability of overlap is $\frac{2}{3}$.
Ofcourse, all of the above can be done by using the joint distribution and using calculus.
